# How can I create button on text message on Unity?

Tags: button, unity-game-engine, coordinates

I'm building an English learning application by Unity and now I get a trouble. Let me describe:
I have a message such as:
"This is ...[No1]...beautiful picture. I like...[No2]...very much.
How could I ...[No3]...it? Could I pay it by...[No3]..."

[No1],[No2] are buttons. Use will tap on them to show the single choice A,B,C,D for each space. But now I don't know how to create button base on that spaces because my app has a lot of messages like that and I have no idea to detect coordinates of buttons.
Please help me, many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a function with an int arg. Then, for each Text, add the Button component and call your function with the answer id.

Example:

This is ...

- [No1] a beautiful picture -> call "myFunction(1)"